# IsolatedStorageFile's MoveFile() method throws IsolatedStorageException

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage, isolatedstoragefile

Description:

The code below is the simplest code I could write which causes the failure. I've also tried: putting the CreateFile and MoveFile in different using statements, putting them in different xaml pages, moving the file into a subdirectory with a new filename, moving it into a subdirectory with the same filename. They all throw the same exception. CopyFile throws the same exception in all circumstances.

Question is--what incredibly simple thing am I not accounting for?

1. Open a new Silverlight for Windows Phone 7 project targeting Windows Phone 7.1.
2. Open App.xaml.cs.
3. Paste the following lines of code into Application_Launching:

   ```
   using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
   {
       isf.CreateFile("hello.txt");
       isf.MoveFile("hello.txt", "hi.txt");
   }
   ```
4. Click start debugging, targeting emulator or device.

Expected: creates a file named "hello.txt", then (effectively) renames "hello.txt" to "hi.txt".
Actual: throws exception below.

```
System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException was unhandled
  Message=An error occurred while accessing IsolatedStorage.
  StackTrace:
       at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.MoveFile(String sourceFileName, String destinationFileName)
       at PhoneApp4.App.Application_Launching(Object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
       at Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.FireLaunching()
       at Microsoft.Phone.Execution.NativeEmInterop.FireOnLaunching()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `Close` after you create the file.

```
IsolatedStorageFileStream helloFile = store.CreateFile("hello.txt");
helloFile.Close();
isf.MoveFile("hello.txt", "hi.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

I was just having the same issue, but the solution is simple:
The target file must not exists, delete it before the moving. Make sure the target file is not open anywhere before deleting.
The source file must not be open anywhere.

```
if (_isolatedStorage.FileExists(targetPath))
{
    _isolatedStorage.DeleteFile(targetPath);
}
_isolatedStorage.MoveFile(sourcePath, targetPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

Perfectly execute this piece of code

```
  var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(oldName);
  await file.RenameAsync(newName);
```

Answer (score 0):

MBen, your answer is not correct.  Calling Close on the file does not fix this error.  I am seeing the exact same error as well even though I call "Close" before MoveFile.

*edit*  Ok just figured out the problem I was having - if you try to call MoveFile when the destinationFile already exists, it throws an Exception.  You have to delete the destinationFile first before moving your sourceFile to it.